# Groovy - Jenkins Pipeline - Groovy CPS doesn't go trough .eachLine method

Tags: jenkins, svn, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run this code inside Jenkins Pipeline script:

```
def getTags = { svnurl ->
    def command = ["svn","ls","${svnurl}"];
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()

    proc.in.eachLine {
        println(it)
    }    
}

getTags('http://svnurlexample.net/');
```

The result should be a list of folders at the svn location but what I am getting is an error:

[Pipeline] echo:

1.0.0/

expected to call java.lang.ProcessImpl$ProcessPipeInputStream.eachLine but wound up catching org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2.call

The proc.in.eachLine is causing the issue, as if Groovy finds the first folder on the location but can not handle the rest and reports an error.

Comment: A couple of longshots: try annotating with `@NonCPS`, or this may be because the `execute` method will always be from the Jenkins master (this code seems build agent independent, but just in case something from the env is impacting here).

Comment: I think `.eachLine` is one of the methods that is not supported in CPS context. To annotate `getTags` with `@NonCPS`, as Matt suggested, you have to turn it into a function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. Could you write a function example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
@NonCPS
def getTags (svnurl) {
    def command = ["svn","ls","${svnurl}"];
    def proc = command.execute()
    proc.waitFor()

    proc.in.eachLine {
        println(it)
    }    
}

getTags('http://svnurlexample.net/');
```